# "nearby" vs "near to"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> 1. He went fishing in the creek **nearby** the grocery store.
> 2. He went fishing in the creek **near by** the grocery store.
> 3. He went fishing in the creek **near to** the grocery store.

Could anyone please show me if there is any difference semantically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearby in the sentence implies "close at hand or adjacent".

**[From TFD....](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/near)**

nearby, adj.

*talking about short distances*.

If something is near, **near to**, or close to a place or thing, it is a short distance from it.

- I live in Reinfeld, which is near Lübeck.
- I stood very near to them.

> When near and close have this meaning, don't use them immediately in
>   front of a noun. Instead **use nearby**.
>
> - He was taken to a nearby hospital
> - He threw the bag into some nearby bushes
> - a nearby town

**He went fishing in the creek near(by) the grocery store.**

Answer (score 0):

**Near by** is not commonly used in this sense by native speakers.

---

**Nearby**, although also an adjective, is more common as an adverb. As in:

> She lives nearby.

Also, while being used as an adjective, it's uncommon to use an article after nearby. See the example sentences in [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nearby):

> But Mr Dodsworth claimed that **nearby residents** had all been in the
> dark.
>
> He believes that **nearby shops** may be using the banks to dump
> cardboard boxes.
>
> And the copper giant has also adopted three primary
> health centres in **nearby villages**.

You see the pattern? *The creek nearby the grocery store* doesn't quite sound right.

---

According to [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/near), **near to** is equivalent to **near** (the proposition).

> *preposition*
>
> (***also near to***) At or to a short distance away from (a
> place):
>
> the car park near the sawmill
>
> do you live near here?
>
> [SUPERLATIVE]: the table nearest the door

The third sentence is correct.

> He went fishing in the creek **near to** the grocery store.

But a native speaker is more likely to drop the pronoun.

> He went fishing in the creek **near** the grocery store.